# Returning an array from a chainlink node job task

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink

i want to return an array from my chainlink node from my smart contract but always get this error

```
encode_data ethabiencode

ETHABIEncode: while converting argument 'value' from <nil> to string[]: cannot convert map[string]interface {} to string: bad input for task: bad input for task

abi: (string[] value)

data: { "value": $(parse) }
```

and this is my job task

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Soccer-Data"
externalJobID = "235b822c-588b-4c96-b77d-ad6bf6220584"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0x1e9C369125f8aE3DE8B43c37dd71EB6D3398F90B"
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = "0"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="soccer-data" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"competition\\": $(decode_cbor.competition),\\"date\\":$(decode_cbor.date)}}"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(string[] value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0x1e9C369125f8aE3DE8B43c37dd71EB6D3398F90B" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```